# Understanding convolution

Tags: convolution

Take:

> $$
> (u*v)(k) = \sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty u(i)v(k-i).
> $$
>
> The $k$ is there, it's because you want to define
>   $$
> \ldots\ldots, (u*v)(-3), (u*v)(-2), (u*v)(-1), (u*v)(0), (u*v)(1), (u*v)(2), (u*v)(3), \ldots\ldots
> >$$
>   etc.  The number in the parentheses is $k$.  Thus, for example, when $k=4$, we have
>   \begin{align}
> (u*v)(4) = \sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty u(i)v(4-i)
> \end{align}
>   $$
> = \cdots\cdots+u(-3)v(7)+u(-2)v(6)+u(-1)v(5)+u(0)v(4)+u(1)v(3)+u(2)v(2)
> >$$
>   $$
> \phantom{={}} {}+u(3)v(1)+ u(4)v(0) + u(5) v(-1) + u(6)v(-2)+u(7)v(-3)+u(8)v(-4)+\cdots>\cdots.
> >$$

Could you give examples of what the 'k' value could stand for?
Can it only be time offset?

Could you give an intuitive explaination why you need to multiply u(-3) with u(7)! And not u(-3) with v(-3) for example? With a diagram for example.

Comment: For a tutorial on convolution of sequences, see the answers to [this question](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/5992/235) or [this one](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/3482/235) on the signal processing stackexchange site dsp.SE.

Comment: To the answers below. Thanks, but please give a answer to question 1 and question 2.

Comment: What values can be used for $k$?  Well, your question includes $4$ as an example of a value for $k$. **Any** integer can be used as a value for $k$, e.g. $5$ or $-15$ or $1095340$. As to "intuitive explanation" please **read** what the formula is saying. _The expression above_ **does not** _ask you to multiply $-3$ with $7$_. What it _does_ say is that if we choose $i$ as $-3$ (remember $i$ can be any integer in that sum), then $k-i = 4-(-3) = 7$ since we have already chosen $k=4$, and so the formula tells us to multiply $u(i)=u(-3)$ and $v(k-i)=v(7)$ together and add them to the sum.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wrote " what the 'k' value could stand for", so what does k actually mean. Not 'which integers can be used as a value for k'. And why does it make sense that you multiply a value left from the y-axes u(-3) with a value right from the y-axes v(7)

Comment: This is crossposted [here](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/8444). Please do not crosspost. If your question is not sufficiently answered on one forum, ask the moderators to migrate your question to another forum.

Answer (score 1):

This may be more than you want, but if these sequences are "on the spectral side", that is, are Fourier coefficients of functions, say $U(x)=\sum_m u_m\,e^{imx}$ and $V(x)=\sum_n v_n\,e^{inx}$, then the usual pointwise multiplication of functions has the effect on Fourier coefficients of convolution. That is, the function $UV(x)=U(x)\cdot V(x)$ has $k$th Fourier coefficient $\sum_j u_{k-j}\cdot v_j$. This follows by a direct computation.

Although this mechanism can obviously be abstracted and formalized, forgetting about Fourier series, etc., I think this structure is the real reason we care. There are other discretized variants, too, but this is the simplest, most natural, and historically first, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I always found it more insightful to look at convolution in a way that's not quite obvious from the usual definitions. However, at least in the discrete case as you her brought forth, it's a completely equivalent, if somewhat weird-looking definition:
$$
  (u_1 \ast u_2 \ast \ldots \ast u_n)(k)
    = \sum_{(i_1,i_2\ldots,i_n)\in \mathbb{Z}^n\colon \sum_m i_m = k} \prod_{m=1}^n u_m(i_m)
$$
or, for just two functions,
$$
  (u \ast v)(k) = \sum_{(i,j)\in \mathbb{Z}^2 \colon i+j=k}\!\! u(i)\cdot v(j)
$$
So you're considering the product of results from (all) the given functions, summed over all ways to evaluate them *such that the arguments sum up to $k$*.

Not sure if that answers your question, but...